# Windows Performance Monitor keeps trying to add unwanted counters

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, performance, monitoring, perfmon

I have been running a Data Collector Set for SQL Server for a week, and everything was going just fine until I tried clicking on Action -> Save Current View and now it always tries to add the following counters automatically to my reports:

```
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1296])\NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1296])\NumberOfNonPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1296])\NumberOfPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1624])\NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1624])\NumberOfNonPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1624])\NumberOfPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1744])\NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1744])\NumberOfNonPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[1744])\NumberOfPooledConnections
\\MYSERVER\Provedor de Dados .NET para SqlServer(sqllogship[2008])\NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools
```

And this causes a lot of annoying error messages (one for each counter listed above) saying:

> One or more of the selected counters are already present and won't be
>   added again.

How do I prevent those counters from being automatically (re-) added everytime I select a report?

Thanks.

Comment: I've done my usual google-fu and this is the first time **ever** I'm not able to find a resolution (in fact I haven't even been able to find any mention to a problem like this), so I finally decided to ask here. It's my first question on a forum in a looong time. I've also tried removing those counters and clicking again on the menu, with no luck.

Comment: Same here, had to redo the DataCollector job in order to have this error get away.

Comment: @neosys well, interesting to know that I'm not the only one that has encountered this problem. I've stopped using reports, and so far I haven't run into this again, but if you put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct, since it still is a solution.

Comment: I re-did my data collector sets and it still does this. in fact this time around it shows the error like 6 times whereas previously it only showed it once.

Answer (score -1):

You have created a Current View. As such, whenever you open a report in Performance Monitor it will attempt to add those performance counters to any log you open. If they already exist you'll receive this error message.

To fix this problem do the following

1. Open a saved report and clear the error messages
2. Right click on one of your performance counters select "Remove All Counters"
3. Hit OK when it asks if you are sure you want to remove all added counters
4. Click "Action"
5. Click "Save Current View"

Problem Fixed.

Comment: ur solution is to delete everything?